# The type of Query.user must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: node.js, graphql

http://localhost:4000/
when I give as input
    
    `{
        user(id: 1) {
            firstName
        }
    }`

I get output
`{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of Query.user must be Output Type but got: undefined.\n\nThe type of Query.user(id:) must be Input Type but got: undefined."
    }
  ]
}`

I am doing this Graphql first time and I am not sure where I am doing something wrong, I see lots of example, but if I do that way, I got lots of other errors. I tried to change InputType from type, but still issues.
server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
var graphQLHTTP = require('express-graphql');
var schema = require('./schema');
app.use(graphQLHTTP({
   schema,
   graphiql:true,}))
app.listen(port);
```

schema.js below

```
const {
GrpahQLString,
GrpahQLInt,
GraphQLSchema,
GraphQLInputObjectType,
GraphQLObjectType,
GraphQLOutputType
} = require('graphql');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const UserType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name : 'user',
    description : "...",
    fields: () => ({
    id: {
        inputType : GrpahQLInt,
    //      resolve: (user) => user.id,
    },
    firstName: {
        inputType : GrpahQLString,
//       resolve: (user) => user.firstname,
        },
    lastName: {
        inputType : GrpahQLString,
//       resolve: (user) => user.lastname,
    },
    email: {
        inputType : GrpahQLString,
//       resolve: (user) => user.email,
        }
    })
});
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name : 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
        user : {
            inputType: UserType,
            args: {
            id: {type: GrpahQLInt}
            },
            resolve : (root ,args) =>
                fetch(`${BASE_URL}/users/${args.id}/`).then(res=>res.json()).then(json=> json.user)
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var graphql = require('graphql');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';


const userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
name : 'user',
description : "...",
fields: {
   id: {
    type : graphql.GraphQLInt,
    },
    firstName: {
    type : graphql.GraphQLString,
    resolve: (user) => user.firstname,
    },
    lastName: {
    type : graphql.GraphQLString,
    resolve: (user) => user.lasttname,
    },
    email: {
    type : graphql.GraphQLString,
    resolve: (user) => user.email,
    },
}
});

const query1 = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
name : 'Query',
fields: {
    user : {
      type : userType,
      args : {
          id: { type: graphql.GraphQLInt}
      },
      resolve : (root ,{id}) =>
          fetch(`${BASE_URL}/users/1/`).then(res =>res.json()).then(json=> json.user)
      }
    }
 });


module.exports.default = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
    query : query1
});
```

Comment: I've downvoted your own answer mainly due to the fact that you have not explained, not even a word, about what was wrong in your first code (even when it's clear enough for people with more experience).  This way, your answer does not help to any future user looking for a solution to its own issue, that might be similar.

This site is about a community of developers helping each other; I'd recommend you edit your answer and explain what was wrong in your own code. Happy to re-vote it afterwards.